# Removing all missing files from Xcode

Tags: xcode, file-management

Does anyone know of a quick way to remove all files from an Xcode project that are marked as missing (colored in red)?

Comment: Can't think of an idea other than selecting them all, right clicking and selecting "Delete"/"Remove".

Answer (score -1):

Hold shift and click on each file to select them, and then right click to delete.
Hope this helps.

Comment: When you have more then 500+ files to remove, that isn't a quick way.

Comment: If you have that many files you should place them in a group (folder)in xcode file->new->group since then deleting the group deletes all the files

Comment: @gheese so how do you get them into a group? Same problem.

Comment: file->new->group - will create a group in project navigator, you can then drag the files you want into the group folder you just created